# Angular cli project dont run with ip address

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Angular cli project run on

```
localhost:4200
```

but it does not run on 
(which is my localhost)

```
10.0.0.30:4200
```

how to run this , with ip address so that i can use it on other system as well.

Comment: Ensure the server serves to this IP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `host` option when serving your app.

`ng serve --host=10.0.0.30`

Comment: or maybe `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: why `0.0.0.0` ?

Answer (score 0):

is it will be `ng build --host=10.0.0.30` while serving a production build?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command :

```
ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```